# Avoid Thread.sleep using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-android

I applied observable to this method, but after calling this method, it is saying too much work on the main thread. Any help is appreciated

```
fun isBatteryHealthGood(): Observable<Boolean> {
        var count = 0
        intent = context.registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))

    while (batteryStatus == null && count < maxCount) {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        count++
    }
    return Observable.just(batteryStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD)
}
```

Comment: Provide code for observing this method

Comment: var status_= disposable.add(batteryTestController.isBatteryHealthGood()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe())..
This what I have written to subscribe to it. I will edit my above code to make is observable. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to avoid usage of Thread.sleep() by using [interval operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html)
I think you can ommit observable in isBatteryHealthGood().

Just return boolean like this:

```
//a simple function works here, no need
fun isBatteryHealthGood(): Boolean {


    return batteryStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD
}
```

and finally subscribe like this:

```
Observable.
            interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            take(maxCount) //place max count here
            .map { _ -> isBatteryHealthGood() }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.maintThread())
            .subscribe {
                batterystat ->
                //do what you need
            }
```

PS: you should register receiver only once

```
intent = context.registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
```

Comment: registering a receiver every second? that doesn't make sense

Comment: you are right, registering this receiver is another problem, i will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

As you want to make an asynchronous method execution. You should consider using Observable.fromCallable() not Observable.just().

Here is detailed article https://medium.com/yammer-engineering/converting-callback-async-calls-to-rxjava-ebc68bde5831

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code. You'd be better off just using a library like [RxBroadcastReceiver](https://github.com/karczews/RxBroadcastReceiver) so you can just write:

```
fun isBatteryHealthGood(): Observable<Boolean> {
    return RxBroadcastReceivers
        .fromIntentFilter(context, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
        .map {
            it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, 0) == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD
        }
}
```

One big benefit is that you don't register the broadcast receiver yourself and don't need to handle broadcasts at all, that logic is contained in the library and is routed through the observable stream.

So there's no need for `Thread.sleep` or `Observable.timer`, which honestly defeats the whole purpose of using a broadcast receiver that is supposed to "push" the changes to you, instead of "pulling" them every second.

Lastly, when you `dispose()` the result of `isBatteryHealthGood()`, it will automatically unregister the broadcast receiver for you.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will check this library.